# Problem trying to connect to a URL and getting an image back as a response in the view - Node.js & Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to make a GET request to a URL and getting an image from there as a response using node and express.

This is my code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('http://tapas.clarin.com', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

The view is showing a `Cannot GET /`.

How can I make this request work properly to show the recieved image in my view ?

**HTML**

```
    <div id="tapas">
        // I want to show the image from the response here!
    </div>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

app.get() is used to create a GET API on your server. What you need is a package that can help you to make API calls to other servers and fetch data from there.

You could use the `request-promise` npm package to make life easier for you.

```
    var rp = require('request-promise');


    var options = {
    uri: 'https://api.github.com/user/repos',
    qs: {
        access_token: 'xxxxx xxxxx' // -> uri + '?access_token=xxxxx%20xxxxx'
    },
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
    },
    json: true // Automatically parses the JSON string in the response
};

rp(options)
    .then(function (repos) {
        console.log('User has %d repos', repos.length);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // API call failed...
    });
```

EDIT: After re-reading your question, you don't really need to do a GET API call and fetch the image on your server before showing it on your website. You could directly pass the URL to your img tag like this -

```
<img src="https://url/image.png" alt="example">
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help ... this worked and I'm getting the HTML back from the page I requested ... this page has 3 inputs for day, month and year which I need the user to fill in before making a second request (POST) with the user's input to this URL http://tapas.clarin.com, do you have an idea on how can I do this too ?

Comment: If you don't mind could you ask a separate question for this and share the link in the comments? Stackoverflow's Q&A style works best if one question is restricted to just one topic. If my answer helped with the question you asked, consider accepting the answer for the benefit of future users who have similar problems. Thank you.